# Strange outline position when attempting to recreate Chrome <input> outline

Tags: html, css

I'm making a custom  that contains an , and my goal is to remove the natural outline/border from the  and place it on the containing  such that it still looks natural when focussed, however, it seems that I am not getting the natural outline appearance and instead it looks like the outline is placed on the outside of the div...

**Natural input element**

[image]

**My custom div containing the input**

[image]

Is there something that can be done to achieve the natural outline look?

I have used `outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;` for the styling on the `<div>`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}

input, .two {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.one {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.two {
  height: 25px;
}

.two:focus-within {
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}

.three {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="one" />
  <div class="two">
    <input class="three"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try giving it a negative [`outline-offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset)? Such as `outline-offset: -1px;`

Comment: You are correct! I didn't see the option to add an offset, thanks. After a bit of trial and error it seems that the correct spacing for my purpose is `2px` :). If you add as an answer, I can accept for you.

Comment: Sure, I wasn't sure it is going to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try giving it a negative [`outline-offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset) such as `outline-offset: -1px;`

It's not pixel perfect, but it does look a bit more like built-in style outline on Chrome:

*But do bear in mind that it might vary for different devices. For me `-1px` looks the best.*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}

input, .two {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.one {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.two {
  height: 25px;
}

.two:focus-within {
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.three {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="one" />
  <div class="two">
    <input class="three"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The *proper* solution might be using [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), which border width is also counted for width and height. So you don't need to do anything to make them look identical.

But it seems not working for Safari.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}

input, .two {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.one {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.two {
  height: 30px;
}

.two:focus-within {
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}

.three {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="one" />
  <div class="two">
    <input class="three"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI - The second solution using border-box doesn't solve the issue - on Chrome at least. The first one was a great help :)